# QT QML not translating text set at runtime

Tags: qt, qml

I have a simple app in Qt 5.9 using QML. The app has one `Text` element which text I am translating and it works fine using the method with the empty string at the end of the text.

The problem is that when I change the text of the `Text` element at **runtime**,  it is no longer translatable.

The text field's text is provided as follows, where `localization.updateLanguage` is the empty string:

```cpp
    Text
    {
        id: txt
        text: qsTrId("test_label") + localization.updateLanguage
        color: "white"
        font.pixelSize: 40
    }
```

The setting of the new text is done when clicked on a button and it works. It sets the text with correct language. But after that when trying to change the language of the new text it doesn't work.

```cpp
    MouseArea
    { 
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:
        {
            txt.text = qsTrId("new_label") + localization.updateLanguage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `new_label` is translated? try to swap these strings ie. set `test_label` at runtime. What a reason to concatenate the string with empty one? Try to remove `localization.updateLanguage` too.

Comment: Yes, new_label is translated. The reason the concatenate with the empty string is a hack solution to force the update of the string with the translation as described by Qt wiki [here](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_do_dynamic_translation_in_QML). They have fixed it after 5.10 and QQmlEngine::retranslate() [slot] can be used but still doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your text is not being translated afterwards is because when you do : `txt.text = qsTrId("new_label") + localization.updateLanguage;`, you are doing an imperative assignement, this won't create a binding, it's evaluated only once.

If you want to create a property binding imperatively you can use `Qt.binding()` :

```
txt.text = Qt.binding(function() { return qsTrId("new_label") + localization.updateLanguage;} )
```

More information here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html#creating-property-bindings-from-javascript

Alternatively you could do that :

```
property string label: "test_label"
text: qsTrId(label) + localization.updateLanguage
// ...
onClicked: txt.label = "new_label";
```

(I don't think lupdate will be too happy with the dynamic `qsTrId` parameter though)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use your bindings, but predefined QML bindings. To retrastalate all interface call this method: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#retranslate

Comment: OP is using Qt 5.9, this method is only available since 5.10